# Is there a site that can track all the domain names I own?

Tags: domain

I've been using a spreadsheet to keep track of domain names. Is there a web service anywhere that maintains a domain name database and tracks all the domains we own? The most important feature is that it would have to remind me when it's time to renew, but it would also keep track of all the registrars in my life.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Domain Monitor will do it.

The only problem being that although they will send you e-mail alerts when your domain status changes, they aren't quite as fast as I would prefer. I was trying to watch a domain I wanted to buy, and the alert they sent came about 8 or 9 hours after the status actually changed.

> [Domain Monitoring with Domain Monitor & more - DomainTools](http://www.domaintools.com/monitor/)

But at least it's free, and it's pretty handy. Also, they claim that they don't sell your "lookups" to squatters (meaning, when you check to see if xyz.com is available, they won't sell that info to a squatter if you don't buy it in 24 hours like many domain services apparently do).

Comment: I'm having trouble adding .co.uk domains, but .com are fine? Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

I currently have all of my domains with GoDaddy and they have a great manager that allows me to easily see all of my domains and gives me 60, 30, 10, and 5 day renewal notices on them. If you could migrate them all there, that would be keen.

If not, I believe mydomain.com has some services you can use to manage your domains, even when they aren't the registrar for them. I used them a long time ago when I was running some servers from home and it looks like the management type stuff is still active.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I keep the list in a, errm, FogBugz wiki page and create cases for the maintenance, including renewal.  The thing I like about this way of doing it is that the wiki/cases lets you easy keep track of everything that's happened in the life of the domains.

Answer (score 3):

[DNZoom](http://www.dnzoom.com/) is a domain portfolio management system that plugs in to various registrars, allowing you to mange domains on lots of different accounts.

Comment: looks very promising

Comment: DNZoom is down.

Answer (score 2):

First, the following solution isn't the best answer for every person every time.

I've become a domain name reseller, for my business needs, but I've found that it's very useful for managing all my own domain names as well.

As domain names expire, I've been moving them over to my reseller account, I get good rates, and they are all in one place, and I can do things like 'bulk whois changes'.

I use tucows, and they also offer free dns service, and have APIs to do everthing via scripts if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any unusual domains, like .com.au?  That may throw a spanner in the works.

Comment: G'day mate! What's so strange about .au, cobber?

Answer (score 1):

I use Google docs to keep track of stuff like that, but it doesn't remind me about upcoming renewals.  I get those email reminders from the DNS vendors or hosting services, I guess.  Maybe you're using the wrong hosting services?  That should be a pretty standard notification for a company like that, I would think.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, I know, but I've setup yearly repeating events in Google Calendar for each domain. Then simply add any other information you need in the event's description (like the registrar).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is useful to you:

http://www.domainpunch.com/products/

Answer (score 1):

Domainrr is a simple tool that allow you to track your different domain account and send you reminder before their expiration: http://www.domainrr.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Are My Sites Up](http://aremysitesup.com/) is a really clean, simple site for tracking website status. It'll notify you (email, SMS, or Twitter DM) if the status changes and give you the HTTP error code.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP is not looking to track his server's uptime, but the status of his domain names, i.e. expiration date, which registrar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Aware Monitoring** provide a service to track your domains, but the emphasis is more about performance and monitoring up time.

Their web site is at [Aware Monitoring](http://awaremonitoring.com/)

They are pretty amenable and if asked may include the extra field in their system to track the renewal date too?

Comment: This service does not seem to provide what the poster asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics
http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: This service does not seem to provide what the poster asked for.

Answer (score 0):

[myDomains](http://rtlabs.ca/mydomains/) is an iPhone app I created for managing domain names; those that you own, or are interested in purchasing.  It has reminder features and can track for any registrar.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Robodomain](http://robodomain.com) for quite some time now. It is probably better than most of the answers that are given here.

I can add all the domain there, they send me emails when a domain is about to expire. When I log in I can see all the details such as WHOIS information, nameservers all that stuff.

It has some other features, not that much, just the stuff you need. It has also a good layour and a nice feel.

I have been using is for about 2 years now, but recently I got an email that they will switch to a paid service, but I can not find any information on that on the website itself. I hop they stay free.

link: www.robodomain.com